# Why not capture the already propagating exception in `std::promise::~promise`

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, c++14, future

Say you have the following code

```
void func(std::promise<int> prom) {
    try {
        auto promise = std::promise<int>{std::move(prom)};
        // .. do stuff
        throw std::runtime_error{"something went wrong"};
    } catch (...) {
        // cleanup and dont bother with the promise
    }
}

auto promise = std::promise<int>{};
auto future = promise.get_future();

std::thread{[promise = std::move(promise)] {
    func(std::move(promise));
}}.detach();

try {
    cout << future.get() << endl;
} catch (std::exception& exc) { 
    cerr << exc.what() << endl;
}
```

What is the reason behind not catching the exception that is propagating when the promise is destroyed and re-propagating the same exception on the future end?  Why is a broken promise exception always thrown in such a situation?

I just feel like its natural to have the same exception re-propagate on the future end.

---

To clarify what I meant, in addition to having the `set_exception()` method, I thought the destructor calling `set_exception(std::current_exception())` could be a good idea

Upon catching the exception and storing a reference to it, the destructor would then rethrow the exception

Comment: You should use `set_exception` to set exception in the promise object.

Comment: @WhiZTiM I am aware of that, I am just wondering why capturing a propagating exception and calling `set_exception` on that is a bad idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A destructor has no exception to catch or rethrow. I think the logic you want is:

- If the destructor detects that it's being called as part of stack unwinding; and
- it would otherwise store a `future_error` with `broken_promise` in the shared state, then
- it stores `current_exception()` in the shared state instead.

Let's ignore the fact that until C++17 you can't portably detect if you are being called as part of stack unwinding; implementations have access to "magic" things that mere mortals don't.

First, you are sharing the exception object across threads *silently*, with all the attendant risks of data races. Sharing things across threads is hard enough without the standard library stabbing you in the back.

Second, an exception on the *producer*'s side may well be meaningless for the consumer. In many cases the consumer doesn't care if the producer failed to produce a value because of a network error or the phase of the moon. All it cares is that the promise was broken.

Answer (score 3):

You propose that `std::promise`'s destructor catch active exceptions and store them.

What does `do_stuff` return under your proposal?

```
int do_stuff(std::future& f) {
  std::vector<int> alice;
  std::promise bob;
  f = bob.get_future();
  throw 7;
  alice.push_back(42);
  return alice[0];
}
```

what does `do_stuff` return?  The `7` thrown was catught in `~promise`, but that bypasses the return value calculation.

I see nothing but insanity down this path.

Exceptions are already a come-from, but at least they are *structured* come-from.  Your proposal requires unstructured catching and would make program flow of exceptions completely beyond anyone's ability to understand.

If it simply duplicated the exception, in general you aren't allowed to do that?  You can store a (smart) pointer to them, but not a copy.

Comment: I think I might have miscommunicated what I meant, in addition to `set_exception` I feel like catching the exception in the destructor could be a good idea.  It's like remote exceptions, the way thrift implements them, an exception thrown on the remote end propagates to the pull end

Comment: @Curious Yes, that is what I understood.  Again, if `promise` magically catches exceptions thrown during its lifetime during its destructor, what does `do_stuff` return?  `promise` catches the exception `7`; what is the return value of `do_stuff`?  Please specify an integer, or should the thrown exception propogate out?

Comment: rethrow the exception and mark the destructor `noexcept(false)`?  Or is there something obvious I am missing here

Comment: @Curious Why would it rethrow?  Your code doesn't rethrow, it catches it and waits for the future to `.get()`'d.  No future was `.get()`'d above.  It should catch it and wait for that.

Comment: yeah might have been a bad idea..  but then again, if something happens and an exception causes a promise to get destroyed, should the `future` not be alerted to that?